# Split a JSON file into separate files with jq and Python

Tags: python, json, jq

I have a JSON file with 100 objects that I would like to convert into separate JSON files, one per each object.

I have written a script in python to do this, but it runs endlessly in my terminal if I try and increment the values in a while loop.

It doesn't crash, it just never finishes.

```
import os

i = 0
while i <= 100:
    os.system(f"cat _metadata.json | jq '.[{i}]' > {i}.json")
    ++i
```

Comment: This can't run at all. `while i <= :` is a syntax error and `++i` should also be a syntax error.

Comment: You really don't need `jq` or `os` module for this. Start with `open('_metadata.json')` and use Python to read that

Comment: BTW useless use of `cat`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 typo when posting the question, program runs just never finishes

Comment: `++i` is still incorrect. Did you want to put `i += 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, piping and output redirection should not be done with a single `os.system` command... Python has its own piping system with `subprocess` module, however, you dont really need that.

Python is capable of doing this on its own

This assumes your file contains just a JSON array

```
import json

with open('_metadata.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  for i, x in enumerate(data):
    with open(str(i) + '.json', 'w') as f_out:
      json.dump(x, f_out)
```